# split string in ',' C++

Tags: c++, string, split

I have a string like this:

`17, the day is beautiful , day`

. 
And I want to split this string in the first ','.
For example I want to take 2 strings. one for ***17*** and two ***for the day is beautiful , day***

Comment: The [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function can actually use any arbitrary character as "line ending", not only newline. It can be used together with [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) for such string "splitting".

Comment: Since you're looking for first of something `string::find_first_of` is a good match ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
std::vector<std::string> strs;
boost::split(strs, "17, 132, asdasd, 111", boost::is_any_of(","));
```

Comment: I have for example two ',' but I want to split only for first. 
In your example I want to take 2 elements in vector 17 and 132, asdasd, 111